# How to receive document from other apps in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile

Hii I am new to React Native, Now I want to receive .txt document files. If the user tries to share a document, I want to place my app in the line

For Example, Check this Screenshot https://prnt.sc/p90k8a

Suggest any npm package, I can't Find.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You provide only very few information about what you try to do. 
But as first step to think about: You need to have a Server (or an Service) which receive and push the messages/data between the Users.

So I recommend to create an Server-API (maybe use something like FeathersJS or Strapi.io). Then you need to create a concept `when`, `who` is able to send/receive `what`.

Maybe this article give you an Idea how to start: https://medium.com/@javiergmezmora/how-to-share-files-between-apps-react-native-ab317c072259